# Neo4j Source Connectors Failing to build the Schema where the source query returns null for some of the fields

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, apache-kafka-connect, avro

I am using Neo4j Source Connector for Kafka (https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/kafka-connect/source/) to produce the changes to the Kafka Topic. My config is like below:

```
{
    "connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.source.Neo4jSourceConnector",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "*****",
    "neo4j.server.uri": "bolt://neo4j:7687",
    "neo4j.source.query": "MATCH (c:Customer) WHERE c.timestamp > $lastCheck RETURN c.name as name, c.age as age, c.timestamp as timestamp",
    "neo4j.enforce.schema": "true",
    "name": "neo4j-source-connector",
    "neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "neo4j",
    "topic": "neo4j-test-AVRO",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "neo4j.streaming.poll.interval.msecs": "5000",
    "neo4j.streaming.from": "LAST_COMMITTED"
}
```

Whenever I inserted a node in the neo4j with the following code:

```
CREATE (c1:Customer {name: 'Test',age:null, timestamp: timestamp()})
```

I got the following error:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

I used the JSONSchema (io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter) but was getting the same error. Things works with the String Converter (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter) though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, here are some possible workarounds achievable by changing "neo4j.source.query":

1. Filter out `Customer` nodes with no `age` property:

   ```
   MATCH (c:Customer) WHERE c.age IS NOT NULL AND c.timestamp > $lastCheck RETURN c.name AS name, c.age AS age, c.timestamp AS timestamp
   ```
2. Use a special value (e.g., -1) instead, if `age` is `NULL`:

   ```
   MATCH (c:Customer) c.timestamp > $lastCheck RETURN c.name AS name, COALESCE(c.age, -1) AS age, c.timestamp AS timestamp
   ```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this workaround but was looking for something else on the connector config side if there were any. Anyways thanks